# How can I send a thanks email in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, smtp

I have to send a thanks email (if someone emails to the particular account they will get automatic email saying "Thanks for sending"). How should I do this in asp.net mvc 2? What is the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a brilliant library **[MvcMailer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MvcMailerNuGet.aspx)**

You can use it to send text or html email, which body you define as a view. You can use whatever model you need and render emails with specific data.

It is available as a [**NuGet**](http://nuget.org/Packages/Search?packageType=Packages&searchCategory=All+Categories&searchTerm=mvcmailer) package for easy install.